# Passing TextBox Text to Navigated Page

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, parameter-passing

I am trying to pass data from a textbox in one page to a text block in the navigated page. I have some code but I am finding an error when running it here is my coding.

From the page I want to send the data from:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {if (txtSID.Text != null)
            {
                string StudentID = txtSID.Text;


                var url = string.Format("/BookingConf.xaml?StudentID={0}", StudentID);
                NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri(url, UriKind.Relative));
            }
```

Code from the Navigated Page:

```
   protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigatingEventArgs e)
    {
        String StudentID;

        if (NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue
            ("studentID", out StudentID))
        {// load event data, and set data context
            ReferanceST.Text = StudentID;
        }
    }
```

The issue is that when I run the application I get an error on the 'OnNavigationTo(NavigationEventArgs e)' saying no suitable method found to override. 
In order to fulfil this i placed the 'if' statement but it made no difference.

Please help me resolve this issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OnNavigatingTo takes the NavigationEventArgs, not the NavigatingEventArgs.

Change your line to:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is happening because you miss named the override method.

The error is the smoking gun

> "no suitable method found to override"

To fix this

```
 protected override void OnNavigationTo(NavigatingEventArgs e)
    {
```

should be

```
 protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigatingEventArgs e)
    {
```

[MSDN Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.page.onnavigatedto%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

Comment: Thank you. I have changed it but I still get the same error.